# How to read local txt file on a client side in javascript on chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, file-io, google-chrome-extension, io

I need to be able to read settings text file in a Chrome extension, but without asking user to set path to this file.

I've tried the following but `XMLHttpRequest()` doesn't work with `file:///path/to/file.txt` URL's in Chrome.

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
x.open("GET","logins.txt",false); 
x.send(); 
myTextFile=x.responseText;
```

How to do that?

Comment: So basically you could read any files from users computer? What do you think users would think about that?

Comment: @Tommi Halonen, it's for packaged chrome app. I want to read a file which is located at the same dir as index.html of downloaded app.

Comment: Okay then, forget my comment! i don't have any experience about chrome apps.

Comment: read http://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works here. Note that I'm using asynchronous request.

#### Files:

```
ls /path/to/extension/
background.js main.html manifest.json sample.txt test.js
```

#### manifest.json:

```
{
    "name"          : "TEST XMLHttpRequest Local File",
    "version"       : "0.0.0.1",
    "manifest_version"  : 2,
    "minimum_chrome_version": "23",
    "app": {
        "background": {
            "scripts": [
                "background.js"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

#### background.js:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.app.window.create('main.html', {
        bounds: {
            width   : 200,
            height  : 300,
            left    : 100,
            top     : 100
        },
        minWidth    : 200,
        minHeight   : 300
    });
});
```

#### main.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TXT GET</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="btn">Get file</button>
    <pre id="log"></pre>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### test.js:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var log = document.getElementById('log');

function xhttpResponse() {
    log.innerHTML += this.responseText;
}

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var x;

    log.innerHTML = "Get file " + (+new Date());
    x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.onload = xhttpResponse;
    x.open("GET", "sample.txt", true);
    x.send();
    log.innerHTML += "\n\n------ REQ SENT ------\n\n";
});
```

#### sample.txt:

```
Lorem ipsum
```

---

#### Result:

```
[_Get file_]

Get file 1392378751700

------ REQ SENT ------

Lorem ipsum
```

Comment: it's for packaged chrome app. I want to read a file which is located at the same dir as index.html of downloaded app.

Comment: OK. I updated your question with relevant tag + some edit in question text to make that clear. It was not mentioned in original question.

Comment: @Qvatra: Note that I updated answer again. If you want to use synchronous request you have to add a `onreadystatechange` function and check for status etc. Also note that you use relative, and not absolute, path to file. Or you could use `var path = chrome.runtime.getURL("filename.txt")`
 giving you something like `extension://sldfkjslflkas/filename.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't have much time to look at it. I will do it in the end of the week.